# Where to deploy symfony2 application

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, configuration

I have developed a symfony application and it's done. 
It's been a couple of days and I can't figure out how to deploy this into a real apache server, when I copy it to the public_html it doesn't work assets don't load properly.
Can some one give me a step by step description of how to deploy it so that when I navgiate to example.com url I see my symfony application.
Thank you

Comment: Have you read the doc? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html

Comment: poorly configured config file ? can you provide some more details as of steps you followed in deploying?\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to deploy your application on a server, you have to configure apache. The best way its to make a virtual host.

Here the documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/examples.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [Capifony](http://capifony.org) which provides a specialized set of tools on top of [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), tailored specifically to symfony and Symfony2 projects. (according to [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html))

The [advantages](http://jeremycook.ca/2012/11/04/continuous-deployment-with-symfony2-jenkins-and-capifony/) of using capifony are,

- deploying is as simple as running `cap deploy` from your project root directory.
- It stores multiple releases.
- It allows you to use SCM(s) to pull your application code down to the server.
- You can configure it to run any batch command during the deployment.
- It performs a transactional-like deployment process (if any step fails, the deployment is 
  rolled back and the current directory points to your last release)

You'll also need to troll through [this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) to figure out how to get your application running under [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot).